# Spring JPA selecting specific columns by condoition

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

How to find data that equals to workId and not equals to employeeId using spring data jpa.I searched in google but I did not find any method.I tried `findByWorkIdAndNotEqualEmployeeId`. But it is not working .So please help me

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's is very good official documentation about [Query Creation in spring data jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)

According to it this one should work:

```
findByWorkIdAndEmployeeIdNot
```